# $_POST variable empty despite javascript autofill

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html form, that is filled out with javascript when a button is clicked. In php, I would like to get the `$_POST` variable, but it is empty dispite setting the element.value to something (obviously after form submission).

THE FIELD ACTUALLY CHANGES TO THE DESIRED VALUE, BUT THE $_POST is still empty.

Html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="post">
    ...
    <input name="price" id="price" type="text"">
    ...
</form>  ...
<span style="float:left"><a onclick="fill_again()" class="button alt 
small">Get last values</a></span>
```

js:

```
function fill_again(){
document.getElementById("price").value =5800;
}
```

php:

```
echo $_POST["price"]; //<--this should be 5800, but it is ""
```

Comment: So what is going to cause the javascript code to actually run?

Comment: from where you are submitting your form? ajax? javascrpt submit? PHP?

Comment: The button has an onclick tag that calls the js function.

Comment: The form is a html form. If I fill out the fields myself, the $_POST variable is set to 5800 as I wanted.

Comment: Do you think that could have been quite relevant to show in the code fragment, so we can see how that is actually coded. As its obviously not working from what you are reporting

Comment: a button has onclick event? but can u please share the js function in your question

Comment: Open the dev tools in your browser `F12` and look at the Network tab when you submit your form. Check what param values you are sending in to the server. This will let you know if it is a JavaScript issue (frontend) or a PHP issue (backend).

Comment: Also using the debugger you can set a breakpoint and check IF the javascript is actually getting executed

Comment: When your function gets executed ?

Comment: Yes, the button has an onclick event. I have posted the complete js function in question.

Comment: Set the name of your function. Actually it's an anonymous function

Comment: you have the JavaScript at the beginning of the file or at the end before the </body> tag?

Comment: I have checked the dev tools and submitted the form. 
The dev tool displays the upload_file.php (which is the action of the form) and the icon file that I use as an icon. Nothing else

Comment: @Vidal: My function gets executed when I click the button. My js is at the end, before the </body> tag, footer and a php function

Comment: @R3tep: Yes sorry, I forgot to pase the function name here, but it is not the issue. It still doesn't work. And actually, the form field changes to 5800. It is just that at submittion, the value is not passed to $_POST

Comment: It seems probable that your form is submitting before the value is set.

Comment: @Lewis: or maybe his page is reload due to `href=` undefine

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my own problem.

I have a js before that modifies the same element:

reNewElement2 = ';'
   document.getElementById("size").innerHTML=reNewElement2;

And I don't know why, but even though this is executed prior to the above script, the value remains as declared here, i.e. there is no value.